# Hover of button fire up when hover of tile fires

Tags: html, css

I'm building an interface on which I have a tile and I'm displaying a button on top of it. What I want is the hover of the button to fire when I hover on the tile, not only when i hover on the button. I've tried some things I knew but they don't work. Here is a fiddle to show you what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/yRH67/1/
Here's the code:

```
<div class="tile black box-alignment" style="width:75%;margin-bottom:0px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-info" style="margin-left:10px">Change picture
            </button>

         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle for details. Can anyone suggest a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add CSS so if .black is hovered, .btn-info changes:

```
.black:hover .btn-info{
    background-color:rgba(51,51,51,255);
    border-color:rgba(51,51,51,255);
    opacity:0.7; 
}
```

**Explanation of coding**

```
 .black:hover .btn-info{
```

Adds the rule so if .black is hovered over, the css is applied to .btn-info

[JSFIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/yRH67/2/)

Comment: I was first! :D (few seconds). Best regards!

Comment: @Jacek, you were, but your jsfiddle does not work! +1 ;)

Comment: You got me! Updated, forget to save. I think it will be fair, to give +1 to both of us :). +1 from me :).

Answer (score 2):

```
.tile:hover .btn-info {styles go here}
```

Is the solution tou Your problem :). Remember that there is a space after .tile:hover. In that case every .btn-info that is a child of .tile with state hover will have the style as follows in the brackets.

I hope I understand Your question OK, and this is the effect that you want to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/yRH67/3/

Answer (score 0):

Put the tile over the button, then it should activate. If you prefer the tile then button interface, you could add an invisible button behind both. Lmk if this doesn't work.